# Docker - unable to build image - fork/exec docker-containerd-shim: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-maven-plugin

I have docker installed on RHEL 7.3. When I try & build the images for services using java as base image it builds them successfully.

But when I try & build my UI image using node:boron as base image, it fails saying :

```
fork/exec docker-containerd-shim: no such file or directory
```

Please help me with this. I have tried restarting the docker daemon & other such workarounds mentioned on web, but no luck.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/sales
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/sales

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/sales
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app/sales

EXPOSE 8182
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

We use fabric.io docker-maven-plugin to build images:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dockerHost>${docker-host}</dockerHost>
                    <certPath>${docker-cert-path}</certPath>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <alias>ui/sl</alias>
                            <name>ui/sl</name>
                            <build>
                                <tags>
                                    <tag>latest</tag>
                                </tags>
                                <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/build/sl/prod/</dockerFileDir>
                            </build>
                        </image>

                    </images>
                    <saveFile>${project.build.directory}/ui-sl.tar</saveFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sl docker:build</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>save</goal>
                        </goals>

                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>op docker:build</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>save</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <images>
                        <image>
                            <alias>ui/op</alias>
                            <name>ui/op</name>
                            <build>
                                <tags>
                                    <tag>latest</tag>
                                </tags>
                                <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/build/op/prod/</dockerFileDir>
                            </build>
                        </image>

                    </images>
                    <saveFile>${project.build.directory}/uiOp.tar</saveFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
             </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile and your build command?

Comment: I have added the DockerFile & docker-maven-plugin config

Comment: I'm not familiar with this plugin, but the error message looks like there is a wrong filename or path. Is `dockerFileDir ` correct? Is the name of the file `Dockerfile` (not `DockerFile`!)?

Comment: Yeah that is all correct.